# How to disable auto-generated GraphiQL filters in playground?

Tags: graphql, graphiql

I couldn't find any reference for disabling auto-generated filters in playground. For instance if a type has `name: String` as attribute, GraphiQL generates `name_contains`, `name_ends_with`, `name_gt`, ... filters which makes the explorer very noisy. How to disable these filters?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to your configuration file. This should work.

```
"tracing.tracingSupported": false
```

Comment: This doesn't work...@noFilter is not recognized

Comment: I edited my answer can you try it ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).